# Outlook 2016 - Accept meeting invite from different email account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

I need to have more control over which email is used in the response to a meeting invitation when I use Outlook 2016.

Here is my setup:

```
dano@domain-one.com  <-- this address has a calendar
dano@domain-two.com  <-- this email does *not* have a calendar
```

I want to be able to accept meeting invitations from "domain-two.com", but have them be saved on my calendar.

Whenever I accept a meeting, it is always accepted from `domain-one.com`. (Even if I try to edit the response and change the "from" field to my `domain-two` address.)

I need to be able to respond to meetings from the email address to which the invite was sent.

Comment: When you open outlook 2016 and go to the calendar on the bottom left there should be a scroll window that can allow you to add 'other calender's' to your primary calendar. Can you edit the email you are responding with when accepting invitations?

Comment: When I try to respond and edit the "From", it still sends the response from my original calendar email. 
I have created a new Calendar under this `domain-two.com` address, and will then just copy the events to my main calendar after I accept. I'll see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

The response to a meeting request only allows the From email to be the default account that has a calendar.  Unlike a normal email, it doesn't allow you to change the From account. Kind of crazy when you think about it.

The only work-around I've found, but seems to work is:

1. Make sure your Send/Receive is set to manual (File, Options,
   Advanced, Send/Receive, uncheck Schedule an automatic send/receive
   every x minutes)
2. Accept the invite (which creates the invite-reply email in your
   Outbox)
3. Right-click the email created in your Outbox and click Forward
4. Modify the From email account in the forwarded email and click Send
5. Right-click the original email in the Outbox and delete it
6. Press F9 to send the new invite reply

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to deal with it is as follow:
When getting the calendar invitation, instead of clicking on **Accept** select the arrow next to **Accept** and choose **Edit the Response before Sending**, then select the From `the correct mail address`

Comment: How does this improve on last year's answer?